# Error. Cannot assign value of type '[UInt32]' to type 'UInt32'

Tags: swift, skphysicsbody, uint32

I get an error when i run my code saying : Cannot assign value of type '[UInt32]' to type 'UInt32' I have added some decent amount of code here, but the problem is within this line :  torpedoNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = alienCategories
I have done some research and tried to solve the problem on my own but i`m stuck with this error. What am i doing wrong?

```
 let alienCategories:[UInt32] = [(0x1 << 1),(0x1 << 2),(0x1 << 3)]
      let alienTextureNames:[String] = ["alien1","alien2","alien3"]

        let photonTorpedoCategory:UInt32 = 0x1 << 0


        let motionManger = CMMotionManager()
        var xAcceleration:CGFloat = 0

        override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

            starfield = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Starfield")
            starfield.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1472)
            starfield.advanceSimulationTime(10)
            self.addChild(starfield)

            starfield.zPosition = -1

            player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shuttle")

            player.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: player.size.height / 2 + 20)

            self.addChild(player)

            self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
            self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

            scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Score: 0")
            scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: self.frame.size.height - 60)
            scoreLabel.fontName = "AmericanTypewriter-Bold"
            scoreLabel.fontSize = 36
            scoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.white
            score = 0

            self.addChild(scoreLabel)


            gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.75, target: self, selector: #selector(addAlien), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


            motionManger.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.2
            motionManger.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { (data:CMAccelerometerData?, error:Error?) in
                if let accelerometerData = data {
                    let acceleration = accelerometerData.acceleration
                    self.xAcceleration = CGFloat(acceleration.x) * 0.75 + self.xAcceleration * 0.25
                }
            }



        }


        func addAlien () {

            //Random index between 0 and 2 changing the texture and category bitmask
            let index = Int.random(in: 0...2)
            let textureName = alienTextureNames[index]
            let alien = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: textureName)

            //Use Int.random() if you don't want a CGFLoat
            let xPos = CGFloat.random(in: 0...414)
            let yPos = frame.size.height + alien.size.height
            alien.position = CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos)

            alien.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: alien.size)
            alien.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

            alien.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = alienCategories[index]
            alien.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = photonTorpedoCategory
            alien.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

            self.addChild(alien)

            let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(y: -alien.size.height, duration: 6)
            alien.run(moveAction, completion: { alien.removeFromParent() })

        }


        override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            fireTorpedo()
        }


        func fireTorpedo() {
            self.run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("torpedo.mp3", waitForCompletion: false))

            let torpedoNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "torpedo")
            torpedoNode.position = player.position
            torpedoNode.position.y += 5

            torpedoNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: torpedoNode.size.width / 2)
            torpedoNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

            torpedoNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = photonTorpedoCategory
            torpedoNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = alienCategories
            torpedoNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
            torpedoNode.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

            self.addChild(torpedoNode)

            let animationDuration:TimeInterval = 0.3


            var actionArray = [SKAction]()

            actionArray.append(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: player.position.x, y: self.frame.size.height + 10), duration: animationDuration))
            actionArray.append(SKAction.removeFromParent())

            torpedoNode.run(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))



        }


        func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
            var firstBody:SKPhysicsBody
            var secondBody:SKPhysicsBody

            if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
                firstBody = contact.bodyA
                secondBody = contact.bodyB
            }else{
                firstBody = contact.bodyB
                secondBody = contact.bodyA
            }

            if firstBody.categoryBitMask == photonTorpedoCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == alienCategories[0] {
                torpedoDidCollideWithAlien(torpedoNode: firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, alienNode: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
                score += 5

            }else if firstBody.categoryBitMask == photonTorpedoCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == alienCategories[1] {
                torpedoDidCollideWithAlien(torpedoNode: firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, alienNode: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
                score -= 5

            }else if firstBody.categoryBitMask == photonTorpedoCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == alienCategories[2] {
                torpedoDidCollideWithAlien(torpedoNode: firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, alienNode: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
                score -= 10

            }
        }

        func torpedoDidCollideWithAlien (torpedoNode:SKSpriteNode, alienNode:SKSpriteNode) {

            let explosion = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Explosion")!
            explosion.position = alienNode.position
            self.addChild(explosion)

            self.run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("explosion.mp3", waitForCompletion: false))

            torpedoNode.removeFromParent()
            alienNode.removeFromParent()


            self.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2)) { 
                explosion.removeFromParent()
            }

            score += 5


        }
```

Comment: Type mismatch: `contactTestBitMask` is `UInt32` (single value), `alienCategories` is `[UInt32]` (array). You might mean `torpedoNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = photonTorpedoCategory`

Comment: Yes! ops. That is where the problem is :         torpedoNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = alienCategories

Comment: @vadian i edited post. But do you have any ideas?

Comment: I know where the error occurs. See my extended first comment.

Comment: @vadian Sir, dont know why i put that there. But thanks . You actually saved me for alot of time here. I have spent 3 hours at this. LOL. cheers!